# Parsing dates with django utils parse_date

Tags: django

I'm trying to use parse_date to convert a string into a datetime object before saving in a DateField however it seems to keep returning nothing.Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
>>> parse_date('13/07/2016')
>>>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm surprised because django has this function and it just fails silently. But anyway, I played with it and it should be:

```
parse_date("2016-07-13")
```

I don't see it well documented and I still use the plain old [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to do date/datetime conversion:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime('13/07/2016', "%d/%m/%Y").date()
```

Comment: thanks I went with strptime in the end as that was just clearer, but good to know it can be done in django